# How do you use regular routes over engine routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-engines

I have a rails application that mounts an engine, to use the engine route Id do `engine_name.route_name_from_said_engine_path` And  to use the regular applications routes I would do `route_name_path`. While this works for non tested code, the second I run my tests, the tests fail, because of the application route "not existing".

My routes File for the application:

```
AisisPlatform::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :application_api_keys

  root :to => 'home#home'

  get 'whats_is_aisis_platform' => 'marketing#platform', :as => 'platform'
  get 'using_aisis_platform' => 'marketing#using_platform', :as => 'using_platform'
  get 'data_syncing' => 'marketing#data_syncing', :as => 'data_syncing'
  get 'help_center' => 'help#help_center', :as => 'help_center'

  mount Xaaron::Engine => ""
end
```

One of my tests, a capybara test, is failing because:

```
Roles Delete role should delete a role (flash)
     Failure/Error: visit xaaron.roles_path
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `application_api_keys_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f80cb84cb48>:0x007f80c65b86c0>
     # ./app/views/layouts/xaaron/application.html.erb:42:in `_app_views_layouts_xaaron_application_html_erb__814247150210445120_70095544064680'
     ...
```

Every test is failing because of this, Yet I can boot up the application and go and visit this route and it works perfectly fine.

This particular route on the `xaaron/application.html.erb` looks like:

```
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><%= link_to 'Users', xaaron.users_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Group Management', xaaron.groups_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Role Management', xaaron.roles_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Permission Management', xaaron.permissions_path %></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Application Api Key Management', application_api_keys_path %></li>
        </ul>
```

My tests are failing because of:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Application Api Key Management', application_api_keys_path %></li>
```

Is there something special I am suppose to do when using application routes over engine routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesnt look like it to me, but if the layout file is in the engine, you need to use `main_app.route_path`. One other thing to note:

"The application doesn't know how to route these requests to the engine unless you explicitly tell it how. To do this, you must set the @routes instance variable to the engine's route set in your setup code:"

```
module Blorgh
  class FooControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    setup do
      @routes = Engine.routes
    end

    def test_index
      get :index
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Sourced from: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#testing-an-engine. Not sure if that's your issue here, but could always try it.